# Why is the value of SE for the transformed regression model higher than the initial model with autocorrelation?

Tags: multiple-regression, econometrics, autocorrelation, standard-error

Is it right that with positive autocorrelation in the errors, the model underestimates the SE? Hence, using generalized differencing (such as Cochrane-Orcutt), the transformed model has a higher value of SE? And if so, what happens to a model with negative autocorrelation? I can't quite explain how these happen.

Comment: Could you provide more details? E.g. autocorrelation in what: dependent variable, independent variables, errors? Also, what do you mean by generalized differencing?

Comment: Autocorrelation in errors and generalized differencing such as Cochrane-Orcutt